# Find XML encoding from InputStream

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding

I have an InputStream containing an XML document and an internal API requires to forward this Document as a String. Therefore I need to determine the encoding. What I am currently doing is something like this:

```
XMLInputFactory fac = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
try (InputStream is = ... ) {
  XMLStreamReader reader = fac.createXMLStreamReader(is);
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
    if (reader.getEventType() == XMLStreamConstants.START_DOCUMENT) {
       System.out.println("Encoding " + reader.getEncoding());
    }
    reader.next();
  }
  reader.close();
}
```

This seems to work but it appears rather clumsy to me to start parsing the document only to find out the encoding. Is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: You need to parse it, because encoding is contained in the XML header line. Still yiu need to parse something. Why not use the same mechanism for both task, you just need to get some information form this xml, and it will be always a parsing operation to do that.

Comment: As I wrote the fixed API requires to convert the input to a String which is then processed later.